# Proving $a$ (in $Y = aX + b + e$) satisfies $a = Cov(X, Y )/Var(X)$

Tags: statistics, regression, linear-regression

In a linear regression model, we postulate that random variables $X$ and $Y$ are related by

$$Y = aX + b + e$$

where a and b are constants (called the regression coefficients) and e (representing random
error) is a random variable independent of $X$ such that $E(e) = 0$.

Show that the coefficient
$a$ satisfies $a = Cov(X, Y )/Var(X)$.

Comment: Write the model as $Y_i = \alpha X_i + \beta + e_i.$ Write the desired regression line (Y on X) as $\hat Y_i = aX_i + b.$ The regression line minimizes $Q = \sum_{i=1}^n (Y_i - \hat Y_i)^2.$ Roughly, one method is to set partial derivatives of $Q$ with respect to $\alpha$ and with respect to $\beta$ equal to $0$ and show that your desired $a$ minimizes the $Q$ as a function of $\alpha$ and $\beta.$

Answer (score 0):

1) Assume that $(X,Y)$ follow bivariate normal distribution, thus 
$$
\mathbb E[ Y |X=x] =\mu_1+ \rho \frac{\sigma_Y}{\sigma_X}(x-\mu_X) = \mu_Y - \mu_X\rho \frac{\sigma_Y}{\sigma_X} + \frac{\rho\sigma_Y\sigma_X}{\sigma^2 _X}x= \beta_0 +\beta_1x \, , 
$$
note that $cov(X,Y)=\rho \sigma_X \sigma_Y$,
hence, $\beta_1 = cov(X,Y)/var(X)$.

2) Assume that $Y=a+bx+\epsilon$, such that $\mathbb E\epsilon=0 $ and $\mathbb E\epsilon^2=\sigma^2$, you can show that the least square estimator of $b$ is given by
$$
\hat b_n= \frac{\sum(Y-\bar{Y}_n)(x_i - \bar{x})}{\sum(x_i - \bar{x})^2},
$$
that can be viewd as $\frac{\sum(Y-\bar{Y}_n)(x_i - \bar{x})/n}{\sum(x_i - \bar{x})^2/n}=\frac{\widehat{cov}(X,Y)}{\widehat{var}(X,Y)}$, that is consistent estimator of $cov(X,Y)/var(X)$, i.e., 
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}P\left(\left|\hat b_n - \frac{cov(X,Y)}{var(X)}\right|>\epsilon\right)=0.
$$